# android rerun handler postdelayed

Tags: android, handler, postdelayed

I am trying to create a textview that changes content four times (replacing it each time in a series) using postdelayed handler that would stop at the end and replay the same sequence after a click of a button.

For some reason I could not understand, the second time around, only the first of the series is played whereas the remaining content is undisplayed.

A sample of the code as follows

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{   
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.page);

    delay1();

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {  delay1(); }});       

}

private void  delay1() 
{    
    final TextView textvie = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.textvi );

    if(apple >= 1)
    {    
         handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
         public void run() {  textvie.setText(" "); 
         if(apple == 1 ) { stop_n_display(); to_stop = 1; } } 
         }, 700 );   
    }
    if(apple > 0)
    {       
         handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
         public void run() {   textvie.setText("1 ";   } 
          }, 710);    
    }
    if(apple >= 2)
    {
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() {  textvie.setText(" "); 
            if(apple == 2 ) { stop_n_display(); to_stop = 1; } } 
           }, 1400 );    
    }

    if((apple > 1) & (to_stop != 1)) 
    {          
         handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
         public void run() {    textvie.setText("2 "; } 
         }, 1410); 
    }
    if(apple >= 3)
    {    
         handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
         public void run() { textvie.setText(" "); 
            if(apple == 3 ) {  stop_n_display(); to_stop = 1;} } 
            }, 2100 );   
    }            
    if((apple > 2) & (to_stop != 1)) 
    {               
         handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
         public void run() { textvie.setText("3 "; } 
            }, 2110); 
    }
    if(apple >= 4)
    {  
         handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
         public void run() { textvie.setText(" "); 
            if(apple == 4 ) {stop_n_display(); to_stop = 1;} } 
         }, 2800 );    
    }    
    if((apple > 3) & (to_stop != 1)) 
    {                       
         handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
         public void run() { textvie.setText("4 "; } 
         }, 2820); 
    }
}
```

Been trying to figure it out for days now but can't seem to find the problem. Please help. I would appreciate any direct fixes or any alternatives to the above method. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is your a problem

```
if(apple > 0){       
if(apple >= 1){   
if(apple >= 2){  
if(apple >= 3){  
if(apple >= 4){
```

It just call to

```
if(apple >0){
```

not call to

```
if(apple >= 1){   
if(apple >= 2){  
if(apple >= 3){  
if(apple >= 4){
```

Because apple > 0 . It alway > 2, 3, 4

fix:

```
if(apple > 0 && apple <1){

}

if(apple >= 1 && apple < 2){

}

 if(apple >= 2 && apple < 3){

}

if(apple >= 3 && apple < 4){

}
```

Comment: I've tried removing the apple conditions before but it didn't work. I've just now adopted your fix and it doesnt work either. To clarify, the 'apple' is to count the number of changes for that series, which can be any number from 1 to 4 times. I've noted 4 times only for simplicity. Also, the sequence works fine in the first instance oncreate. It only fails to display the subsequent content (except the first one) when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Sample code to countdown numbers. Call `dealy1()` method `onClick` of a button.

```
int apple;
private void delay1() {
    apple = 0;//sequence start from 0
    final TextView textvie = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textvi);
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            textvie.setText(String.valueOf(apple++));//series 0 1 2 3 4
            if (apple != 5)//stop counting when apple reaches 5
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);//one sec delay
        }
    }, 1000);//one sec delay
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you share with me the codes if the value of apple varies between changes, i.e. not 1 sec apart for each so I can try to implement it?

Comment: Yes. There is a delay for the pause 20 ms and for the actual text which lasts 700 ms.

Comment: I am confused how your interval timing are working.. but you change time for each next number at this line `handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);`..